# Simplify binom sum: $\sum_{j=0}^{a}\sum_{k=0}^{b} \dfrac{\binom{a}{j} \binom{b}{k}}{\binom{a+b}{j+k}} x_{i}^{a-j}x_{i+1}^{j} y_{i}^{b-k} y_{i+1}^{k}$

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

**Question:** Is there a way to simplify this double sum of binomials?

$$\sum_{j=0}^{a}\sum_{k=0}^{b} \dfrac{\binom{a}{j} \binom{b}{k}}{\binom{a+b}{j+k}} x_{i}^{a-j}x_{i+1}^{j} y_{i}^{b-k} y_{i+1}^{k}$$

**Description:**
I'm integrating an arbitrary function $f(x, \ y) = x^{a} y^{b}$ over a line with extremities $p_i$ and $p_{i+1}$

$$p_i = (x_i, \ y_i)$$
$$p_{i+1} = (x_{i+1}, \ y_{i+1})$$
$$p(t) = (1-t)\cdot p_{i} + t\cdot p_{i+1}$$

$$
\begin{align}
I(a, b, p_i, p_{i+1}) & = \int_{line} f(x, \ y) \ ds \\\\ &
= \int_{0}^{1} x(t)^{a} y(t)^{b} |p_{i+1}-p_{i}|\ dt
\end{align}
$$

After some manipulations I get

$$
I(a, b, p_i, p_{i+1}) = |p_{i+1}-p_{i}|\sum_{j=0}^{a}\sum_{k=0}^{b} \binom{a}{j} \binom{b}{k}  x_{i}^{a-j}x_{i+1}^{j} y_{i}^{b-k} y_{i+1}^{k}\int_{0}^{1} (1-t)^{b+a-j-k} \cdot t^{j+k}\ dt
$$

As

$$\int_{0}^{1} t^{r}(1-t)^{s} \ dt = \cdot\dfrac{r! s!}{(r+s+1)!} = \dfrac{1}{r+s+1}\cdot\dfrac{1}{\binom{r+s}{r}}$$

Then

$$
I(a, b, p_i, p_{i+1}) = \dfrac{|p_{i+1}-p_{i}|}{a+b+1}\sum_{j=0}^{a}\sum_{k=0}^{b} \dfrac{\binom{a}{j} \binom{b}{k}}{\binom{a+b}{j+k}} x_{i}^{a-j}x_{i+1}^{j} y_{i}^{b-k} y_{i+1}^{k}
$$

Then I got stuck. Is there a way to simplify this double sum of binomials?
I found so far that:

$$
(a+1) \cdot I(a, 0, p_i, p_{i+1}) = |p_{i+1}-p_{i}| \cdot \dfrac{x_{i+1}^{a+1} - x_{i}^{a+1}}{x_{i+1}-x_{i}}
$$

$$
(b+1) \cdot I(0, b, p_i, p_{i+1}) = |p_{i+1}-p_{i}| \cdot \dfrac{y_{i+1}^{b+1} - y_{i}^{b+1}}{y_{i+1}-y_{i}}
$$

But for any $a, b \in \mathbb{N}^{+}$ I did not find. I tried to get it using `sympy` of `python`, but it's not very intuitive. For exemple:

$$
\dfrac{3}{|p_{i+1}-p_{i}|} \cdot I(1, 1, p_i, p_{i+1}) = x_{i}y_{i} + \dfrac{1}{2}x_iy_{i+1}+ \dfrac{1}{2}x_{i+1}y_{i}+ x_{i+1}y_{i+1}
$$

**Motivation:** I want to integrate an arbitrary polynomial function $g(x, y)$ in a polygon domain. I transform the integral over the domain in an integral over the boundary (like shown [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/425647/double-integral-in-a-polygon-domain)) and then I want a general expression using the vertex values:

$$
J = \int_{D} g(x, \ y) \ dA = \oint_{\partial D} f(x, \ y) \ ds = \sum_{i} \int_{\text{line},i} f(x, \ y) \ ds = \sum_{i} I(a, b, p_i, p_{i+1})
$$

Comment: It may help to observe that $$\dfrac{\binom{a}{j} \binom{b}{k}}{\binom{a+b}{j+k}}=\dfrac{\binom{j+k}{j} \binom{a-j+b-k}{b-k}}{\binom{a+b}{a}},$$ since there are now no variable indices in the denominator.

Comment: It helps for computational purpose cause we divide only once, instead of doing it for every iteration. I also got something interesting using [wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum_%7Bk%3D0%7D%5E%7Bb%7D+binom%28j%2Bk%2C+j%29*binom%28a%2Bb-j-k%2C+b-k%29+*+y%5E%28b-k%29+*+z%5Ek):  $$\sum_{k=0}^{b} \binom{j+k}{j} \binom{a+b-(j+k)}{b-k} y_{i}^{b-k}y_{i+1}^{k} = y_i^{b} \binom{a+b-j}{b} \ _{2}F_{1}\left(-b, j+1; -a-b+j; \frac{y_{i+1}}{y_i}\right)$$ $\ _{2}F_{1}$ is the hypergeometric function